# How to trigger a Spinnaker pipeline by schedule or time?

Tags: spinnaker

I have a pipeline setup in Spinnaker where it cuts and deploys a nightly build.  I like this to start running at 2am everyday.  But I couldn't find any option or documentation on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When editing your pipeline, click "Add Trigger" and then choose "CRON" as the trigger type. There is a tooltip on the "CRON Expression" field that gives some help on how to construct the cron expression.

Thanks,
-Matt[image]